# 2.82 bone selection is acting wierd

Tags: armature, selection-tools

I’ve used armatures before in older versions, but in 2.82 now every-time I to select the whole bone it only selects the joint, and it cycles through them too. I’m not sure what to do?

Comment: I would suspect you are in edit mode rather than pose mode.

Comment: Yes, I’m trying to set the armature up.